# Having an issue with select max

Tags: sql

I have a column that has entries such as 86D12345, 86A12345, etc. I need to be able to do 2 things:

1. Select MAX value of this column
2. Add 1 to get the next number

This column is nvarchar, so I assume I will have to utilize the substring function plus the select MAX, but cannot seem to get the results. Example is when I run this query:

```
select substring(convert(numeric(5,0), certno),4,len(certno))+1 from maxcertno
```

I get:

```
Argument data type numeric is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
```

Same error with cast

Any ideas?

Comment: You are currently trying to convert the entire field  to numeric before selecting the substring, which is causing the error. You need to put the `convert` outside the substring.

Comment: Is the string always fixed format, ie does the numeric value you want always start in the same position?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format if fixed like `nn N nnnnn` (without the blanks).

This gives the next value (`12346`):

```
cast(substring(certno, 4, len(certno)) as int) + 1
```

And this gives the whole string incremented by 1 (`86D12346`):

```
left(certno, 3) + cast(cast(substring(certno, 4, len(certno)) as int) + 1 as nvarchar(50))
```

With the max function:

```
select 
    cast(substring(max(certno), 4, len(max(certno))) as int) + 1,
    left(max(certno), 3) + cast(cast(substring(max(certno), 4, len(max(certno))) as int) + 1 as nvarchar(50))
from YourTable
```

The last is probably not a good solution in that it's repeating max all over the query. Better to get the max value first and then apply the logic. Or maybe make it a function or stored proc.